# Is it possible to remove one item at a time from a new int[]

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator, delete-operator

```
int *ptr_Array;
ptr_Array = new int[5];
```

Is it possible to remove the last element in the array?
I can PUSH the ints on one at a time.
I can delete the whole array.

```
delete []ptr_Array;
ptr_Array = NULL;
```

I can't find a way to POP the elements off.

I tried the following and loads of other attempts.

```
ptr_Array[i_IastItem] = NULL;
```

I just can't figure it out, I have been trying all day.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, I'm trying to figure out memory allocation and wanted to write my own version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by using a `std::vector` instead.

```
std::vector<int> x;
x.push_back(42);
x.pop_back();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to figure out memory allocation and pointers

Comment: @derek then no, it's impossible to clear one element of an array. You can create a new array of smaller size, copy all elements but the last one, and delete the original array, but that's about it. Once you allocate an amount of memory, you're stuck with it until you delete all of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's kind of what I thought but wasn't sure, now I am, your suggestion of copy and reallocation is the only way to go. Your Comment and the comment of sidran32 below has answered this for me.Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to resize an array to something larger or smaller than what you allocated already, you have to reallocate it. There's not many options for this:

1. You create, resize, and destroy the array using `malloc()`, `realloc()`, and `free()`.
2. You create the array with `new[]` and fill it, then create another array of the new size with `new[]` and fill it accordingly, and finally `delete[]` the old one.

Then of course you could use `std::vector` but you already stated you don't want to do that.

The operating system allocates blocks of memory at a time. If you need more memory, you aren't guaranteed that adjacent memory locations are available for use, so you have to reallocate the whole thing + the additional space again. De-allocating part of the array is also not something that is typically supported. I don't know specifics as to why, but I assume that it's likely because it would make partitioning memory that much more difficult if every program could allocate more than it needs and then free up memory that it doesn't in small bits and pieces here and there. You would end up fragmenting your memory all over the place. The freed memory probably wouldn't be useful to other programs simply because you're freeing memory piecemeal--you can't put a program, array, or anything else in that small hole.

Comment: Well, I would love to up vote, but I didn't have enough reputation points, you need 15, I only had 13. Now I have 18 I will try to upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Simple code to just remove the last element:

```
int size = /* insert size of array here */;
int new_ptr* = new int[size-1];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size-1; ++i) {
    new_ptr[i] = ptr_Array[i];
}
delete[] ptr_Array;
ptr_Array = new_ptr;
```

There, what you wanted is done. The `ptr_Array` is now an array of the same values in the same order, except the last element was popped off and the array has a size less 1 from before.

But to be honest, I agree with other answerers and think you should use `std::vector` in C++. Arrays can be a headache, especially because you always need to keep track of its size in another variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pop and push items as you wish, anywhere, however you want, read about the std::vector class.

Answer (score 0):

An array cannot have anything pushed into it or popped out of it. Arrays in C++ have a fixed size, and while you can give them the illusion of having push / pop operators, the array itself does not have these.